# Como criar o efeito fade em um link que utiliza sprite?

Tags: html, css

Criei um link com um efeito de transição, porém não acontece um `fade`, mas sim um movimento do background.

HTML

```
<a class="botao" href="#">Contrate agora</a>
```

CSS

```
.botao {
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWNy.png) 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 transparent;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s; 
}
.botao:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s; 
}
.botao:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
    -moz-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
    -ms-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
    -o-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
}    
a {text-decoration:none;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/3/)

Como eu faço para que ocorra o efeito `fade` na transição do background?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com fora do lugar? É aquela linha branca que aparece em cima da linha preta, na parte de baixo?

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema, não está claro o que você quer.

Comment: não, tipo, eu coloquei uma transição, porém ele não ocorre o fade, e sim ele só muda a posição do background. http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/3/

Comment: É que você está animando efetivamente o background position, por isso não tem o fade. Para ter fade, teria que animar outra propriedade

Comment: Você poderia me dá uma ajudinha?
Também pensei em usar jQuery/Javascript para criar algum efeito legal...

Comment: Olha os botões desse site: http://www.hoteldaweb.com.br/hospedagem-de-sites/
Ele usa uns efeitos jQuery.

Comment: Eu sugiro reformular um pouquinho a pergunta e o título, para refletir melhor o desejo pelo efeito do fade. A expressão "fora do lugar" fica muito vaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela minha experiência e por [essa outra resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079330/css3-fade-effect), não é possível fazer *fade* de opacidade entre dois `background-image` utilizando apenas CSS3.

O que você teria que fazer, seria criar dois elementos sobrepostos, com `background-image` diferentes, e animar suas respectivas `opacity` via CSS3 Animation.

Se quiser mesmo fazer em JavaScript, esse código aqui serve de exemplo, não utiliza nenhuma funcionalidade muito nova, e funciona no Chrome, Firefox e até no IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .container, .botao {
            font: normal 16px tahoma;
            text-align:center;
            width: 150px;
            height: 40px;
            color:#FFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container {
            position: relative;
        }
        .botao {
            padding:10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }
        .frente {
            background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWNy.png) 0 -100px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .tras {
            background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWNy.png) 0 -150px;
            z-index: 0;
        }
        .container:active .tras {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
            -moz-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
            -ms-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
            -o-transition: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <span>Botão 1:</span>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="botao frente" style="opacity: 1;" id="el1">TESTE</div>
    <div class="botao tras">TESTE</div>
    </div>

    <span>Botão 2:</span>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="botao frente" style="opacity: 1;" id="el2">TESTE 2</div>
    <div class="botao tras">TESTE 2</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonMouseChanged(fadingIn) {
        //Trabalhando com o Closure a nosso favor ;)
        var _this = this, animate;
        animate = function () {
            var o = parseFloat(_this.style.opacity);
            if (_this.fadingIn) {
                o += 0.05;
                if (o < 1)
                    setTimeout(animate, 1000 / 60);
                else
                    o = 1;
            } else {
                o -= 0.05;
                if (o > 0)
                    setTimeout(animate, 1000 / 60);
                else
                    o = 0;
            }
            _this.style.opacity = o;
        };
        this.fadingIn = fadingIn;
        setTimeout(animate, 1000 / 60);
    }

    function buttonMouseEnter() {
        buttonMouseChanged.call(this, false);    
    }

    function buttonMouseLeave() {
        buttonMouseChanged.call(this, true);    
    }

    function prepareButton(id) {
        var btn = document.getElementById(id);
        btn.onmouseenter = buttonMouseEnter;
        btn.onmouseleave = buttonMouseLeave;
    }

    prepareButton("el1");
    prepareButton("el2");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Repare como o valor da `opacity` de `el1`, e de `el2`, começa definido como 1, para poder fazer o `parseFloat()` funcionar sempre.

Para fazer a animação melhorar um pouco, seria interessante não utilizar um valor fixo (como 0.05) para somar e subtrair do `opacity`, mas um valor proporcional ao tempo decorrido desde a última execução da função `animate()`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54228/discussion-on-answer-by-carlosrafaelgn-como-criar-o-efeito-fade-em-um-link-que-u)

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz aqui um exemplo utilizando `opacity`, veja:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="botao"><span>Contrate agora</span><span></span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.botao {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    width:120px;
    height:30px;        
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWNy.png);
}
.botao span:first-child{
    z-index:30;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    left:0;right:0;margin:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.botao span:last-child{z-index:29;
    position: absolute;  z-index:0;  
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWNy.png);
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
}
.botao:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/5/)

Referência utilizando sprite: http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/

Comment: Obrigado! @Paulo Maciel ficou ótimo, agora é só integrar.

Comment: o seu ficou excelente, porém, só não tem a trasição no IE. eu achei isso: http://www.toprated.com.br/static-content/jquery-button/
Obrigado paulo pela ajuda! :D

Comment: acho que vou usar seu exemplo, até porque eu acho que estou usando muitos scripts, vou dar uma maneirada.

Esse acima ele usa jQuery, ele faz com que ao passar o mouse sobre o botão acontecer o opacity com uma transição.

Comment: eu atualizei seu código: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/6/ olha ai como ficou! ;)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes ficou bom! E para funcionar no IE você deve usar filter:alpha(opacity=valor); olha em http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ exemplos

Comment: eu fui tentar colocar no meu site é ficou bugado, acho que foi por causa do `position:absolute`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes falando assim fica dificil identificar o problema, se estiver ocorrendo algo que esteja quebrando o seu layout, faça uma nova pergunte e coloque screenshot e o código para poder ser melhor analisado

Comment: Obrigado @Paulo Maciel vou tentar concertar, qualquer dúvida eu posto aqui.

Comment: Eu coloquei o que você disse, funcionou, só que ficou bugado... Abre ele no IE pra você ver como fica: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Yn8/10/

Comment: se não fosse esse mini-bug ficaria perfeito...